# TilePane: como criar evento individual nos botões

Tags: array, layout, matriz, eventos, javafx

tenho uma dificuldade em usar o TilePane, não consigo criar um evento para cada botão do array. Segue o código para vocês me ajudarem.

```
   `TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
    tilePane.setPrefColumns(3); //preferred columns
    tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Button[] buttons = new Button[9];


    for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {

        buttons[j] = new Button("" + (""), new ImageView(BUTTON_CLOSE_IMAGE));
        buttons[j].setId("btn_transparent");
        buttons[j].setPrefSize(90, 90);
        tilePane.getChildren().add(buttons[j]);

        // Aqui tenho um layout com nove botões em três colunas, mas quero que cada         //botão tenha um código diferente. como fazer isso?


    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

estava errando quanto ao local em que estava colocando o evento, mas fazendo várias tentativas, acabei conseguindo:

```
TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
tilePane.setPrefColumns(3); //preferred columns
tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Button[] buttons = new Button[9];


for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {

    buttons[j] = new Button("" + (""), new ImageView(BUTTON_CLOSE_IMAGE));
    buttons[j].setId("btn_transparent");
    buttons[j].setPrefSize(90, 90);
    tilePane.getChildren().add(buttons[j]);
```

}

```
 buttons[0].setOnAction(e -> System.out.print("oi")); // Minha resposta
```